# Custom Post Types not queried in Custom Taxonomy archives or Native archives

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have declared a selection of custom post types as an array, allowing `post_tags` but not `categories`:

```
// Add Multiple Custom Post Types

add_action('init', 'all_custom_post_types');

function all_custom_post_types() {
  $types = array(
    array('the_type' => 'mama',
      'single' => 'Mama',
      'plural' => 'Mamas'),
    array('the_type' => 'webinar',
      'single' => 'Webinar',
      'plural' => 'Webinars'),
    array('the_type' => 'video',
      'single' => 'Video',
      'plural' => 'Videos'),
    array('the_type' => 'discount',
      'single' => 'Discount',
      'plural' => 'Discounts'),
    array('the_type' => 'faq',
      'single' => 'FAQ',
      'plural' => 'FAQs'),
  );

foreach ($types as $type) {
  $the_type = $type['the_type'];
    $single = $type['single'];
    $plural = $type['plural'];
    $labels = array(
      'name' => _x($plural, 'post type general name'),
      'singular_name' => _x($single, 'post type singular name'),
      'add_new' => _x('Add New', $single),
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New '. $single),
      'edit_item' => __('Edit '.$single),
      'new_item' => __('New '.$single),
      'view_item' => __('View '.$single),
      'search_items' => __('Search '.$plural),
      'not_found' =>  __('No '.$plural.' found'),
      'not_found_in_trash' => __('No '.$plural.' found in Trash'),
      'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => true,
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_position' => 5,
      'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','author','comments','excerpt'),
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'exclude_from_search' => true,
      'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' ),
    );
    register_post_type($the_type, $args);
  }
}
```

As can be seen, the arguments allow for `public => true;` and `has_archive => true;`.

I've also set up a custom taxonomy to work as Categories for CPTs only:

```
function topics() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Topics', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Topic', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Topics' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Topics' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Topic' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Topic:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Topic' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Topic' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Topic' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Topic' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Topics' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'topics', array( 'discount', 'video', 'webinar' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'topics', 0 );
```

My problem is that when calling the archive pages for these The CPTs are simply not being found. Tags shared by CPTs and standard posts return only the latter, and `topics` archives or tag archives with only CPTs assigned return empty.

I can see from my markup that the correct templates are being called (tag.php, taxonomy.php) but all are empty.

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tags shared by CPTs and standard posts return only the latter, and `topics` archives or tag archives with only CPTs assigned return empty.

As for the tag archives, that's a default behavior in WordPress core, i.e. tag (`post_tag` taxonomy) and category (`category` taxonomy) archives will only query posts where the type is `post`.

However, the [`pre_get_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) can be used to include custom post types in the main posts query on tag and category archives, like so for tag archives and your CPTs:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_tag() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'mama', 'webinar', 'video',
                                         'discount', 'faq' ) );
    }
} );
```

As for the `topics` archives, they're empty because you set `exclude_from_search` to `true`, which not only excludes the post type from search results, but also taxonomy/term archives.

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#exclude_from_search): (formatting by me)

> **Note:** If you want to show the posts’s list that are associated to taxonomy’s terms, *you must set `exclude_from_search` to `false`* (ie : for call `site_domain/?taxonomy_slug=term_slug` or `site_domain/taxonomy_slug/term_slug`). If you set to `true`, on the taxonomy page (ex: `taxonomy.php`) WordPress will not find your posts and/or pagination will make 404 error…

So to fix the `topics` archives, either set the `exclude_from_search` to `false`, or you could use the `pre_get_posts` hook like the example for tag archives:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_tax( 'topics' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'discount', 'video', 'webinar' ) );
    }
} );
```

Comment: fantastic answer sally – thank you so much. it not only works, but i learned something, not much more to ask for! m